# conectar socket.io-client en React con servidor en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, socket.io

Tengo un servidor en node.js  y espress.js para un clon de instagram.  Dentro de esta aplicacion existe una subaplicacion de chat que funciona con socket.io. El cliente de esta subaplicacion es react en combinacion con socket.io-client.Hasta ahora, puedo conectar exitosamente el cliente con el servidor si escribo el codigo para la conexion del socket en el archivo index.js.
Sin embargo, lo anterior no es compatible con el resto de mi aplicacion ya que al usar express, estoy empleando rutas y controladores.
Es decir, quiero organizar la logica de la aplicacion de chat de manera compatible con la aplicacion principal de forma tal que tenga un archivo de rutas y otro de controlador.

El problema es que al organizar los archivos de la manera en que muestro a continuacion, socket.io-client, mediante el metodo "io.connect(url)" no puede encontrar el servidor.

Lo que espero del codigo que muestro a continuación es:

1. el metodo io.connect apunta a la ruta en donde hay un socket escuchando el evento "connect".
2. En el archivo server.js estan definidas todos los "endpoints" del servidor. Solo muestro dos de ellas incluido el del socket.
3. en el endpoint app.use('/socket'... se encuentra un middleware que lleva a cabo la conexion del cliente con el socket.
4. Este middleware, crea un nuevo ervidor que escucha en el puerto 5001. Ademas se escucha por el evento "connect" que ocurra en el cliente.
   5.Por lo anterior, como resultado, deberian de imprimirse lo siguiente en la consola de node.js:
   a. app is running in port 5000
   b. socket connection running on port 5001
   c. user : (alguna socket.id)
   No obstante, lo que de hecho sucede es que no se lleva a cabo la conexion entre sockets.
   Unicamente obtengo la siguiente impresion :
   app is running in port 5000
   Este es el lado del cliente con React.js:

```
//App.js
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5002/socket") //este es el servidor del socket
```

Asi es como estoy intentando generar la conexion del lado del servidor con Express.js

```
//server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const swaggerDocs = require('./swagger')
const socketConnection = require('./middleware/socketConnection')



app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

swaggerDocs(app)
app.use('/authentication', require('./routes/authentication'))
app.use('/socket', socketConnection, require('./routes/chat'))



module.exports = app
```

```
//index.js
const app = require('./server')

require('dotenv').config()

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('app is running in port 5000')
})
```

```
const app = require('../server')
const serverSocket = require('http').createServer(app)
const {Server} = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(serverSocket, {
    cors: {
        origin : "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})


const socketConnect = ()=>{

    io.on('connection', socket=>{

        console.log('user :', socket.id)
        socket.on('join', (roomId)=>{
    
            socket.join(roomId)
            console.log(`user ${socket.id} has join the room : ${roomId} `)
    
        })
        socket.on('send', async(messageObject) =>{
            console.log(messageObject)
            socket.to(messageObject.roomId).emit('receive_message', messageObject)
            await client.connect()
           const newMessage = await client.db('chat_test').collection('room').updateOne(
                {_id : new ObjectId(messageObject.roomId) }, {$addToSet : { messages : { 
                    author : messageObject.author,
                    content : messageObject.content,
                    time : messageObject.time
                }}}
            )
            console.log(newMessage)
            
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
            console.log('user disconnected : ', socket.id)
        })
        
    })
    
    serverSocket.listen(5001, ()=>{
        console.log(' socket connection running on port 5001')
    }) 

    next()
}

module.exports = socketConnect
```

Comment: [Websocket](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) es una tecnología que aprovecha un socket único de conexión TCP para el intercambio de datos de forma bidireccional. ¿Porqué pretendes usar 2 puertos TCP diferentes para lograr la conexión de socket? Estás tratando de separar la comunicación por socket, lo cual es totalmente opuesto al diseño de la tecnología. Te recomiendo un repaso de la documentación de [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/) para que puedas aplicar correctamente su uso a tus necesidades. Saludos

Comment: no estoy usando dos puertos para lograr la conexión de sockets. Solo uno, el puerto 5001. Este es un clon de instagram entonces el puerto 5000 maneja autenticacion, subir comentarios y dar like a fotos etc. El puerto 5001 es para la aplicacion de chat. En esta subaplicacion, es donde estoy usando socket.io. Como mencioné, si escribo el codigo del middleware en index.js, todo funciona exactamente como espero. Es solo cuando uso  rutas y modulos que la conexion no se lleva a cabo.